# Google Code Attached issue

Tags: command-line, google-code

I have been trying to use the library provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167283/Google-Code-Upload-Utility), but I always get an error.

The command I am running:

```
GCUpload.exe -u:myUserName -p:myPassword -n:myProjectName -s:Test -f:myFile
```

but I get the error of:

```
    That's an error. Your client does not have the permission to get URL /files from this server.
    (Client IP address: <My IP address>)

    Please sign in to upload a file.
```

I can log in to google code with the user and the project exists. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this issue? Thanks.

EDIT: Maybe some credentials must be provided, but I'm not sure what is needed. I've tried this command without success:

```
net use \\code.google.com\projectname /user:username password
```

The error is:

```
The network path was not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have run the command with my google user's password, but there is a separate Google Code password which can be found [here](https://code.google.com/hosting/settings), but you have to be logged in to see it.