# How to auto upload attachment file to Google Site?

Tags: java, c#, file-upload, google-sites

I have a file ( lets say text ) on my local computer shared with some other people on network. As it is local I can't access the file from some other place via internet. So I uploaded a copy of text file on Google site. Now what I want is whenever someone edits text file, I want it get uploaded to Google site.
So that latest copy can be accessed from outside. I can't use drive or Drop-box sync. They are blocked.

Any help or alternative solution is appreciated. I am not looking for any paid alternative. I am comfortable with C++, C# or Java for solution.

I found a duplicate question.But it is 4 years old. API must have deprecated by this time.
[Upload file to a Google Site from C# Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888095/upload-file-to-a-google-site-from-c-sharp-code)

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use google docs/sheets for the document and then link the document or directory in the site.

given the appropriate permissions users can then do what they want

you can then edit the document, and using google drive on your pc, and that will auto-upload and be reflected in the site